# Error displaying when click the user from the activity -> responses tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, firefox, activity

In the user profile, **Activity -> responses -> revisions** or **answers** tab, in the list of items if you are click any user's name it will redirect to its profile page, before that it is showing an error for a less than a second.

But I didn't see any error in the console or network. The error is :

> Error occurred when loading body

GIF for the same:

[image: responses tab]

**Update:** I can see this error message in Mozilla Firefox and not in the Google Chrome.

Mozilla Firefox: 59.0b11 (64-bit)
OS: Windows 7