# Error message when trying to open user profile from responses page, but only for answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tooltips, error-message

If you are trying to open a user profile from responses (from [answers tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=answers&StartDate=2020-01-15%2021:11:34Z)) error message will appear:

> Error occurred while opening post body

> [image]

No errors in console.

**FF 72.0.1 (64-bit)**.

Comment: Norepro in Chrome 79.0.3945.88 64-bit. Althought it does expand out the answer before opening the user page, which is a little weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error displaying when click the user from the activity -> responses tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307249/error-displaying-when-click-the-user-from-the-activity-responses-tab)

Comment: Moving to leave this open because I've actually tried that before, and that bug was fixed a while ago (that post wasn't updated for some reason), and this is a regression of that. Also, this has a status tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue that only happened in FF. It is now fixed.